# Does CoffeeScript support generator function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, generator, ecmascript-6

Does anyone know the answer? If yes, are there any version requirements on coffeescript? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Coffeescript 1.9.0 now supports generators

```
perfectSquares = ->
  num = 0
  loop
    num += 1
    yield num * num
  return

window.ps or= perfectSquares()
```

Answer (score 0):

What iLemming was saying, plus it also supports async generators:

```
range = (from, to) ->
  for i in [from..to] 
    yield Promise.resolve(i)

console.info(i) for await i from range(0, 10)
```

I wrote a blog post about synchronous and asynchronous iterables and generators in CoffeeScript [here](https://medium.com/east-pole/coffeescript-async-generators-and-iterators-e6de45211017).